# R add multiple different inputs interacted within an lapply function

Tags: r, lapply, interaction

I am trying to run a complex repeated function in r using lapply to create multiple datasets and perform multiple similar analyses. My base function works fine, essentially being the following:

`models <- paste0("outcome", 1:10, " ~ explanatoryvariable | fe_variable |0|fe_variable") |> lapply(\(x) felm(as.formula(x), data = df))`

I then plot models based on that formula:

`plot1 <- plot_model(models[[1]],  show.values = TRUE, value.offset = .3, vline.color = "Blue", vline.size = 0.1, p.threshold = 0.05, colors = "Black", digits = 3)`

I do this for all plots 1-10. This allows me to perform the same regression analysis for multiple versions of `explanatoryvariable`, which are all included in my dataset with their corresponding number 1-10.

This works perfectly, however I now need to repeat this with a more complex formula. I need to add an interaction term to the orginal function. However, the variable being interacted is not the same between each model. Essentially, I need the following:

`models <- paste0("outcome", 1:10, " ~ explanatoryvariable*interactionvariable(x) | fe_variable |0|fe_variable") |> lapply(\(x) felm(as.formula(x), data = df))`

Where `interactionvariable` changes for each model.

So, when I create the plots

`plot1` will include `explanatoryvariable` interacted with `interactionvariable1` but `plot2` will include `explanatoryvariable` interacted with `interactionvariable2`, and so on.

Because of the way my function with `lapply` was written before, I cannot insert this changing interactive variable into the pasted text. Is there a way to design an `lapply` function with these two changing inputs? How can I change the code to preserve the overall function for multiple models/plots, but adjust it for this more complex interaction term? Is it possible to have to sets of changing variables within the `lapply` function, especially given that they must be part of an interaction term?

*Note: `plot_model` is from the `sjPlot` package and `felm` is from the `lfe` package*

**Update with attempts using `map` function**

I tried using the `map` function and seem closer but am receiving errors:

```
input_fun<-function(data, input1, input2){
  felm(as.formula(paste("outcome",input1," ~ explanatoryvariable*",input2, "| fe_variable |0|fe_variable", collapse = "", sep = "", data = data)))}
```

```
model <-map(.x = 1:2, .f =  ~ input_fun(data= df, input1 = 1:10, input2 = c(interactionvariable1,interactionvariable2, ...)))
```

which returns the following error:

`Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:69:396: unexpected symbol`

I also tried:

```
input_fun<-function(data, input1, input2){
  felm(as.formula(paste("outcome",input1," ~ explanatoryvariable*",input2, "| fe_variable |0|fe_variable |data = df", collapse = "", sep = "")))}
```

```
model <-map_chr(.x = 1:2, .f =  ~ input_fun(data= df, input1 = 1:10, input2 = c(interactionvariable1,interactionvariable2, ...)))
```

and received:

```
Warning: invalid formula c("outcome1 ~ explanatoryvariable*interactionvariable1 | fe_variable |0|fe_variable | data = df", "outcome2 ~ explanatoryvariable*interactionvariable2 | fe_variable |0|fe_variable | data = df")...: assignment is deprecatedError in class(ff) <- "formula" : cannot set attribute on a symbol
```

As @allan suggested, `map` seems to be on the right track, but how can I fix these errors?

Comment: Your example isn't reproducible, but it sounds as though you are looking for `Map`, which is like `lapply` except it can take arbitrarily many lists or vectors which it will pass one element at a time to the function.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thanks and apologies for the lack of reproducible code. I have tried using the ```map``` function and appear closer but am still generating errors. Any suggestions for the proper syntax using the map function?

Comment: For an [rlang style lambda function](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/as_function.html) you need to provide `.x` as an argument. So in your code, this is where you want `input_fun()` to use `1:2`.